# How use PromQL search metrics with time range

Tags: promql

I am learning prometheus query langue.How to find metrics with time range, like between 2020-08-01 and 2020-08-30

Comment: Please clarify scope of what you are doing. Are you simply running your query in Web console of Prometheus? Or you want to use these metrics as part of bigger query (and if so - how)? Or you doing something else?

Comment: I am try  query in Web console of Prometheus

Comment: Enter your query, switch to graph tab, and set range 30d and end time 2020-08-30. Like this: https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=up&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=30d&g0.end_input=2023-08-30%2000%3A00%3A00&g0.moment_input=2023-08-30%2000%3A00%3A00